# Detect node from html string and extract image inside in PHP

Tags: php, html, string, dom

I'm locked on something that make me crazy, if you can help me, would be cool !

I have a string containing a valid HTML code. In this PHP code I would like to detect a specific image via the class of his parent, and extract the url of the image + update it with another url.

Here is an example :

```
$html = '....<div class="header">...<img src="theimage.png" />...</div>...';
```

I would like to parse the $html string, extract the url "theimage.png" and replace it by "theimage2.png" (after some internal working)

I tried to use a REGEX, but I'm not sure it's the best solution, because I need to be sure that only the image in .header will be returned, and I need to execute some functions to get the name of the future link.

Maybe the solution is to parse the HTML with DOM Node, but it didn't work too.

Can you help me please ? Thanks !!!

Comment: Would you like an answer without to use any third party `API`??

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [SimplePHPDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

**PHP**

```
$html = '<body><div class="header"><p>some html</p><img src="theimage.png" /></div></body>';
$html_dom = str_get_html($html);

foreach($html_dom->find('.header img') as $element) {
    echo $element->src . '<br>'; // output src of img inside .header div
}
```